# Can't figure out how to make a subquery

Tags: sql, database, subquery

```
        CREATE TABLE TBLTeams
(
    teamnm        varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    teamid          varchar(10),
    rondenm         varchar(10) 
    primary key(teamnm)
)

CREATE TABLE TBLWedstrijd
(
    thuisteamnm        varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    uitteamnm            varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    wedstrijdid            varchar(10) 
    primary key(wedstrijdid)
)

alter table TBLWedstrijd add foreign key (thuisteamnm) references TBLTeams(teamnm)
alter table TBLWedstrijd add foreign key (uitteamnm) references TBLTeams(teamnm)

CREATE TABLE TBLUitslag
(
    thuisteamnm        varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    uitteamnm            varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    wedstrijdid            varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    uitteampunt            int,
    thuisteampunt        int 
    primary key(thuisteamnm)
)

alter table TBLUitslag add foreign key (wedstrijdid) references TBLWedstrijd(wedstrijdid)
```

If I update teamnm in TBLTeams how can I update reference in TBLWedstrijd uitteamnm. I know its a subquery but I really dont know how.

Comment: Can you specify the query of what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: Is this SQL Server?  *(Or MySQL, or Oracle, or PostgreSQL, or MariaDB, or......)*  You probably want to look in to the `CASCADE` keyword for when you set up the foreign key relationships.  You also should be ***very*** cautious of amending these keys after they've been created.  It's nearly always a bad idea.  That's why there are surrogate keys, usually integers to improve performance.  *(In SQL Server these are `IDENTITY` columns.)*  Having such columns allows you to store the volatile string keys in just one table, and then use the integer surrogate key in the other tables for foreign keys.

Comment: Also: Strong advice to use surrogate keys for PKs and FKs.

Comment: You INSERT values, no need to update.

Comment: Another tip: Have ID's as integer data type.

Comment: @jarlh - It's a normal pattern to inherit `identifiers` from external systems, that use non-integer values.  It's also unfortunately common for these external identifiers to be volatile.  This ***appears*** to describe the OP's case; instantiate a team, reference that team in multiple tables, then the team's external identifier changes.  The OP wants this change to be propagated to the other tables.  This means that changing the existing fields to INT would be insufficient and the OP *(may)* simply needs to start using `IDENTITY`/`AUTOINCREMENT` columns as surrogate keys.

Comment: Yet another tip: you dont need {`thuisteamnm`,`uitteamnm`} in table `TBLUitslag`; since you already refer to  `TBLwedstrijd`, containing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going about it a bit wrong. If you're going to change the teamname, you shouldn't use it as a key (Since that will break all references).

You'll want to reference their IDs from the TBLWedstrijd instead of using their name.

So your statements will become:

```
CREATE TABLE TBLWedstrijd
(
    wedstrijdid        varchar(10),
    thuisteamid        varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    uitteamid          varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    primary key(wedstrijdid)
)

alter table TBLWedstrijd add foreign key (thuisteamid) references TBLTeams(teamid)
alter table TBLWedstrijd add foreign key (uitteamid) references TBLTeams(teamid)
```

The same is valid for your table TBLUitslag, you should only reference TBLWedstrijd, since that one already holds the info about which teams are playing. Not to mention, the score is pretty much part of a game anyway so it doesn't make a lot of sense to seperate those into 2 tables. So that becomes:

```
CREATE TABLE TBLWedstrijd
    (
        wedstrijdid        varchar(10),
        thuisteamid        varchar(10) NOT NULL,
        uitteamid          varchar(10) NOT NULL,
        uitteampunt        int,
        thuisteampunt      int 
        primary key(wedstrijdid)
    )
```

This is called "table normalisation" if you wanted to google some stuff for more info about it.